# Post on page with impersonate access_token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have a question, I'm trying to post on a page with the token acquired from

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
>        client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
>        grant_type=client_credentials

I guess the app has permission to post on that page, but when I try to post I get the following error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

How do I verify the permission?

Basically, I want to be able to post to a page as a page without asking user to login, Would be great if someone can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

The token that you are acquiring is an **App Access Token**.

And to post on a page as a page itself, you need a **page access token**.

To get the page access token, you need to make the following API call with an access token with `manage_pages` permission:

```
/{page-id}?fields=access_token
```

this will give you the page access token for your pages. Use that and publish the post.

You can also have a never-expiring page access token. To get one follow this: [What are the Steps to getting a Long Lasting Token For Posting To a Facebook Fan Page from a Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261813/what-are-the-steps-to-getting-a-long-lasting-token-for-posting-to-a-facebook-fan/18322405#18322405)