# What are the Steps to getting a Long Lasting Token For Posting To a Facebook Fan Page from a Server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-page, restfb

I have a Business Page in Facebook (known as a Fan Page in Facebook vernacular).

I want to `post to that Page` whenever a user takes a certain action on my app.  I want to post as the Page itself rather than a user (i.e. from my personal account). The post will come from my outside server (I am using restFB).

I have gone through the steps of authorizing my personal account with appropriate `manage_pages` permissions for the Page. I have also gotten an access token for the page.  I have even been able to post to that page as the page as I wanted to.  The problem is that the token that I get (through their developer tools graph explorer) has an expiration of an hour.  I need it to last much longer than that, preferably forever.

I've looked around the internet, including SO for the answer and most posts point back to the horrid FB docs or make vague references to hooking my outside application to a facebook application and posting through that.  I've tried to make that work but I am confused by the whole process, quite frankly (what is a callback address, for example?).

Anyway, I'd love to see step by step instructions in plain English on `getting a long lasting access token` that I can use to post from one application to a facebook Fan Page.

Please do not refer to the FB documentation.  It is terrible.  I've been through it a dozen times at least.

Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here are some steps you can follow to get a never expiring token for your fan page:

1. Firstly, you need to get the long lived user access token (that expires in 2 months). To get this, make the following call:

   ```
   GET /oauth/access_token? grant_type=fb_exchange_token& client_id={app-id}& client_secret={app-secret}& fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
   ```

   More details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/#generate-long-lived-token). Let me know if you had any difficulty with this.
2. Get the never expiring access token for your page using the token you obtained in the above step (not the normal token, that's the main difference here):

   ```
   $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");
   ```

So the concept is, to get the long lived page token you should use the long lived user token while making the call.

Comment: I guess I am confused about the app-id and app-secret.  How do I set up an facebook app for the page?  What does a facebook app do?  Is it necessary to have one just to update the fan page?

Comment: Yes you need a facebook app. There's no such `facebook app for the page`, just simple facebook app which you can create from here: http://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up getting it working with your advice and Sebastian C.  I wish I could give you both the reward.

Comment: is there any chance how to create new FB app and join that with our current FB page (we have thousands fans in our FB page, so we can´t start from nothing again).

Comment: What do you mean by join?

Comment: Where can I make the GET requests?

Comment: What do you mean by "WHERE"?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MYCLIENTID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=MYCODE

the way how iam calling above is getting the temparary accesstoken.
similarly please give an example url to get the perminent acesstoken

Comment: @SahilMittal: This has to be done only once at the time of login right? Or at time when the request fails?

Answer (score 15):

@Shadowfax is complety right.
Just to complete the workflow:

1. Get the short term user access_token with the facebook login, and with the `manage_pages` permission.
2. Send this short term user access_token to your server
3. From the server, make the @Shadowfax request:

   `GET /oauth/access_token? grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={your-app-id}& client_secret={your-app-secret}&fb_exchange_token={short-lived-user-access_token}`

   with host `graph.facebook.com` and port `443`.

   You have to make this request from the server because it contains your app secret key.
4. From the server, you now are able to query facebook by replacing the user access_token by this long-live version
5. From the server, obtain the page access_token by using your long-live user access_token, either by querying the user account:

   `GET /{user-id}/accounts?access_token={long-live-token}`

   You will obtain all the user's pages with their id and access_token.

   Or you can querying directly the specific page if you already know its page_id

   `GET /{page-id}/?fields=access_token&access_token={long-live-token}`

As @Shadowfax said, this page long-live token will last forever, as long as the user (you) doesn't revoke your app permission.

Comment: Some typo I guess: 2 months*. And updating the long-lived token is not required I guess, since OP needs the fan page token, which will never expire in future. (just a single time query)

Comment: thanks for the typo! I guess he will need the 'admin_user' long-live user_token, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, but just for one time. It's a one time query to get the fan page token

Comment: you're right, I had never seen this update before. Thanks again!

Comment: Where can you send the GET requests? Can I use the form on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?