# news feed from facebook wall to a android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

There is any way to get the last post's made on a facebook wall into a Android app? I want to make some like a RSS reader to get some information on the app.

To explain better-

I have a page on facebook about one football club and there I post several information about news, games etc. Now I have made an android app and my question is whether I can import the post into the android application?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course, you can. First of all, if you are new to facebook integration- read the basics of the android integration, login/authorization calling its APIs etc. (not complex at all).

Facebook provides many APIs (for different functions) that uses the [**access token**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

Based on your requirement, you just need to use the API: `/PAGE_ID/feed` with the `page access token` to get the feeds of your page.  The page access_token can be obtained with the API: `me/accounts?fields=access_token,name` ([Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts%3Ffields%3Daccess_token%2Cname)) after the user authorization/login.

You can test this API here: [**Graph API Explorer**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=PAGE_ID%2Ffeed), using the default token already present there.

---

**Smarter way**

(Without using the facebook API)

Since your requirement involves only back-end processes, you can use this method.

1. First of all, get the Long-lived page access token (that never expires). Detailed steps [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261813/what-are-the-steps-to-getting-a-long-lasting-token-for-posting-to-a-facebook-fan/18322405#18322405). You can use the short-lived token from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).
2. Use this token and make a `\GET` request to :

   > https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=TOKEN_FROM_STEP_1

   (You can check the result in the browser)

This is it!

Comment: thanks for you help.
this will put on the correct way to try to make that. I'm new on this, many many thanks

Comment: @sahilmittal The link you posted works, but it just returns a bunch of JSON data. How do you convert that into a Facebook activity feed?

Comment: I found the answer. I'd hoped there was some library to do it, but I couldn't find one. Instead, I used this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/) from AndroidHive.