# Auto Post to Facebook with PHP SDK like RSS Graffiti

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I want to post auto on facebook with php SDK like RSS Graffiti does so i have this script on every thing is good and working but i am facing one problem here is my script

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => 'appId',
            'secret' => 'secret',
            'fileUpload' => true
        ));   


$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$access_token = $_SESSION["fb_".$fb_appId."_access_token"];

$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$fbuser = $user_id;

echo $accessToken ;
```

this script take accessToken and store it into mysql so i can use it for 60 days ..
i am using this app for myself only so i am using mysql instead of RSS, so post go dialectally on FB as it get posted on my site ...

**Problem:**

Every time i want to get accessToken i have to login to facebook manually (can it be done automatically to get just token)?

can i use my login details in SDK to auto login and get accessToken ? if so how ?

i want to get accessToken every 60 day to make it working.

so please help

Comment: Where did read this from - `$access_token = $_SESSION["fb_".$fb_appId."_access_token"];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have lot of confusions regarding the [**access token**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

Please remember following points about the `user access token`-

1. **Short-lived token** can only be obtained with the user interacting your application( more specifically- when the user login/authorizes your app)

   Validity: upto 2 hours
2. **Long-lived token** can **only** be exchanged with short-lived token. Using the following request:

   ```
   GET /oauth/access_token?  
     grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
     client_id={app-id}&
     client_secret={app-secret}&
     fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
   ```

   Validity: 60 days

So, it's quite obvious that if you want to refresh the login-lived token (before it expires), you're going to need a short-lived token which you can obtain  by sending the person back to the login flow used by your application (not re-authorization really, but just to obtain the new token)

You can read more about Expiration and Extending Tokens on the developers site [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending).

**EDIT**

If you just want to post to your fan page, you can use the `page_access_token`. A never-expiring fan page token could be obtained with a one-time process; and you can use that to do the actions on your page.

See the accepted answer of this discussion: [What are the Steps to getting a Long Lasting Token For Posting To a Facebook Fan Page from a Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261813/what-are-the-steps-to-getting-a-long-lasting-token-for-posting-to-a-facebook-fan/18322405#18322405)

Comment: thx for replying ... 1st i dont want user to login with ...its just to update my posts to facebook page. so i am using Long-lived token.i am obtaining this tocken once in 60 days by getting my self login and storing it in database. 2nd - what i want is ... i dont want to login manually ... is there a way that i can set corn job for it to just login on my behalf and generate token and store in my database? 3rd $access_token = $_SESSION[ this read SESSION of my o\login to get token.

Comment: Obviously it is not possible what are looking for. But if its all about a fan page you can use the never expiring page token. Ive updatd the ans. Ps dont forget to mark /accept ans if helped