# Android facebook page photo fetching

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I want to fetch all the my facebook fan page images to an android app. im the admin of my page and using curl with graph api i can get the images from page. But problem is the access token,the token i generate from facebook developer console,gets times out frequently.

Then i read user token will get timed out,but apptoken wont. so is there a way to fetch my fan page images to present in my android app with app access token.

I would love to get a tutorial on this topic,or some explanation on how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the App Access Token for this purpose. Instead, use the **page access token**, and the good thing is that you can have a **never** expiring page token.\

Follow the steps here to get a never-expiring page access token: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322405/1343690

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the link,but as of now,ive managed to create a short access token for my app with manage page permission. But step two of you arent working for me and also sebastian c's answer is not working as well.

So i now have an 2 months user access token. So can you tell me how to extend it as never ending page token please ?

Comment: Simple. Use tha 2 months user token to query: `/me/accounts?fields=access_token` - this token will be never expiring token. And if its not, pls check your 2 months user token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Yes thank you,now it worked great. One little thing,if i share a image from a page,and later through graph api im getting those feed result,but how to get the link which if users share ,facebook will post it as shared my pages photo instead of the original pages photo that i shared?

in short im asking how to get the share link of my share to make user share my feed that i shared from other page?