# Permanent access token to an app that posts to a fan page - error code:1

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm following the steps very well described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18399927/2510225 , but, from my server, I receive the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"The access token does not belong to application APP-ID","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

I can't figure what I'm doing wrong. Anyone knows if the process to get a permanent access token has changed, or is having the same issue?

The access token I'm using in the request is the user access token, which I think is correct.

**In other words, I'm using this:**

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

With the app_id and app_secret of the app I want to publish on a page and the short-lived-token of the user that have created the app. Is that the right way?

**Edition** (Image to complement answer from @Sahil Mittal)
That's where I'm taking the API_ID (red arrow). That's correct, right?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to replace `APP-ID` with the relevant App ID.

You can get the same from the app settings

---

To get the short-lived-token:

```
if(empty($code))
{ 
    $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
                . "client_id=" . $APP_ID
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                . "&scope=publish_stream,email";

    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}
else 
{
    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                    . "client_id=" . $APP_ID
                    . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                    . "&client_secret=" . $APP_SECRET
                    . "&code=" . $_REQUEST["code"];

    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];
}
```

Comment: Mitta Thank you very much. I added a picture to show you where I'm taking the APP-ID from. That's correct?

Comment: Like this:
**https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=123456789&client_secret=1234567865657656&fb_exchange_token=CRi2dzgiantstringIGRvcprLwZDZD**

Just masked the IDs and cut part of the page access token (its really big)

Comment: I added some more information to make the question more clear.

Comment: What `short-lived-token` are you using in the url? (most prob this is the error) This token is the user's access token for that application; which is obtained from the login flow or it can also be obtained from the server side (ive added the code)

Comment: thank you very much. I posted a road map of how I made this works. I'll put a +1 in your reputation as soon as I have reputation do to that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, That's how I've solved this, combining both solutions given [here][1] with some tries. :

1) Associate the app with the page (It was probably done)

```
http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=_APP_ID&pages=1&page=_PAGE_ID
```

2)Take the CODE given here:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=_APP_ID_&scope=manage_pages&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

**There will be a very fast output on the URL box of your browser, copy that fast. This output should be like this**

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?code=1234546bigstringwithlotsoflettersandnumbersdfdarsd#_=_
```

3)Use the CODE to take the short lived access token of the USER (I guess it can be the same get with the Graph API Explorer))

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=_APP_ID_&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_secret=_APP_SECRET_&code=_CODE_
```

4)Convert the short lived access token to a long lived access token (user yet):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=_APP_ID_&client_secret=_APP_SECRET_&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=_SHORT_LIFE_ACCESS_TOKEN_
```

**You can check if this access token is long lived in
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken**

4) Go to Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), click on the "X" to clear the access token box, and fill in the long access token that you created in the previous step.

5) On the box bellow, choose /ACCOUNT/, to see all the pages of the user this access token is related with. The acess token of these pages are never expired access token, which can be verified in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

That's how it worked for for me.

Comment: Perfect, worked for me and saved me a lot of time with the facebook documentation!
For the last step I did this instead to get a long lived access token for the page (from my long lived user access token)
GET /{page-id}?fields=access_token