# Facebook Link Publishing Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

Using the code under ... when ever i try to post a link to facebook page it posts as my account but when i remove the link below it post it as the page itself .... ? I want to post the link too but as the page !!!

```
if(isset($_POST['title']) and $_POST['title'] != '' ){

    try{
        $message = array(
            'message' => $_POST['title'],
            'link' => $_POST['link'],
            'title' => $_POST['title'],

        );
        $url = '/'.$_POST['pageid'].'/feed';
        $result = $fb->api($url, 'POST', $message);
        if($result){
            echo 'The data is posted!';
        }
    }

    catch(FacebookApiException $error){
        echo $error->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, the **page access token** for posting. This will post as a page whatever you post.

To do this, simply give an additional parameter in your parameters list- `access_token`.

To get the page access token, you should have the `manage_pages` permissions, and api is- `/me/accounts?fields=access_token`. This will list all your pages, with the page access token.

You can also have a never expiring page token, see here: [What are the Steps to getting a Long Lasting Token For Posting To a Facebook Fan Page from a Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261813/what-are-the-steps-to-getting-a-long-lasting-token-for-posting-to-a-facebook-fan/18322405#18322405)