# Post a message to the wall of a page as this page (not the admin)

Tags: facebook, perl, facebook-graph-api

I want to post to a page named XY and it should appear on the page directly and not as a posting from another user (the admin). This is the code I adapted from http://qscripts.blogspot.de/2011/02/post-to-your-own-facebook-account-from.html but this posts to the area for other users not to the main page. If I replace the page-id number by "me" it posts to admins page and correctly to the main area.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I/opt/ActivePerl-5.16/site/lib/

# http://qscripts.blogspot.de/2011/02/post-to-your-own-facebook-account-from.html

use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use LWP::Simple;
use YAML;
use JSON;
use URI;
use utf8;

my $access_token = 'top secret';

graph_api('1484559088426611/feed', {
  access_token => $access_token,
  message      => 'Hello World! I’m posting Facebook updates from a script!',
  description  => 'You want to create a script to read messages and post status updates to your own '
                . 'Facebook account, but you find the official documentation confusing and '
                . 'you aren’t sure where to start. Search no more because here you’ll find '
                . 'the easiest way to do just this.',
  method       => 'post'
});


exit 0;

sub graph_api {
  my $uri = new URI('https://graph.facebook.com/' . shift);
  $uri->query_form(shift);
  my $resp = get("$uri");
  return defined $resp ? decode_json($resp) : undef;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While posting on a page, if you use the access token of a user/admin the post will be published as the user/admin but not as a page itself.

To post on a page as a page itself you should use the [**page access token**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens). To get a page access token you need the permission `manage_pages` and you can make a call to `/{user-id}/accounts`. This way you will get the access token for your page.

Now the good thing is that you can have a page access token that **never expires**! I've explained with steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322405/1343690

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! And for wrapping this GET I need another perl script, right?

Comment: Ah and `manage_pages` is set within facebook, right? If I am the admin of this page, I should be fine, shouldn't I?

Comment: Why the other script? You can add that in your current script only. The permission needs to be set before getting the token. I'm not sure how exactly are you getting the token (using login flow or graph api explorer)

Comment: OK. It works, but if I want to remove the posting, FB complains: The content you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired, or you may not have permission to view this page. Hm. I can hide the stuff though.

Comment: How are you removing the posting? You can remove the posts with the `\DELETE` `/post_id`.

Comment: No, I tried to do this on the facebook page itself. With the facebook gui.

Comment: Of course you can delete. There could be some bug with facebook. Trust me, you can delete those posts with facebook gui and also with the api