# Facebook Error 100: You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a published post

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I just had to do this. 
Absolutely every question I looked up questions regarding this issue but none of their answers helped me solve it.

I am trying to post on my Facebook page.

Here is the issue:

Error:
**"(#100) You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a published post"**

Code:

```
FB.api(
    "/100177680105780/feed",
    "POST",
    {

        "message": "This is a test message",
        "scheduled_publish_time": Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 120

    },
    function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response && !response.error) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    });
```

I have no idea why this is giving me this error. It doesn't work even if I add the "object":{} around the content of the post. I tried changing the UNIX time stamp, I tried changing the message, I tried setting **"published": false** and no luck.

Any guidance would be amazing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"published": false` should be set in order to publish the scheduled posts. If you carefully see the error after you set this parameter, it says:

> (#200) Unpublished posts must be posted to a page as the page itself.

The scheduled posts can be published only using the **page access token** - logical enough  since those who have the permission to manage the pages can schedule the post.

Also, with your code (where you are using a normal user access token), the post is published as yourself not on behalf of the page. And these posts are visible on the side bar not on the main wall- that's not what you are looking for right? :)

So, use the **page access token**. To get the page access token, get the new user token first with `manage_pages` permission and make the call-

```
\GET /{page-id}?fields=access_token
```

Use this token and make the call to schedule the post-

```
FB.api(
"/{page-id}/feed",
"POST",
{
    "message": "This is a test message",
    "scheduled_publish_time": Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 120,
    "published": false,
    "access_token": "{page-access-token}"
},
function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
});
```

I'm not sure about what exactly your application does, but if getting a never-expiring page access token helps you you can see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322405/1343690) here for the same.

Hope that helps!

**Edit:**

As @Tobi has mentioned, also make sure UNIX timestamp is between 10 minutes and 6 months from the time of publish. Since you are using 2 minutes, that may also create problem.

Comment: When the photos are part of a scheduled post, the published, scheduled_publish_time, and unpublished_content_type parameters must be included.

Comment: @VansuitaJr. Yes, but for photos, you will be using the different endpoint - [`/photos`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo).

Answer (score 8):

The docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#scheduledposts are saying that `scheduled_publish_time`

> should be a UNIX timestamp that is the between 10 minutes and 6
>   months from the time of publish

As you're only adding 120 seconds, I guess this could be the reason why it doesn't work. Try adding at least 600 seconds and test it again.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/#pubfields says this as well.

As @Sahil mentioned, you also need to use a Page Access Token, which needs to be set manually as he described.

Comment: Even that wont work since she's using the user access - for which scheduled posting is not allowed

Comment: You're right, but setting the publishing time only 2mins ahead won't work either...

Comment: Plus one to the time gap you must add [10 minutes to 6 months] !

Comment: +1, it's the publish time has to be greater than 10 mins. The error message from facebook is misleading. I thought it was something wrong with my token...

Comment: How can we know that scheduler post published or not?