# Facebook Page Access Token can be used to post stuff?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have read some introduction about Facebook's access token on http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

What I want to ask is that can the page access token of Facebook be used as a permanent token if I just want to post something on the wall like user access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't ever follow the third-party documentation for the facebook integration. They have the [official documentation](http://developers.facebook.com) pls follow that. For access tokens read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

> What I want to ask is that can the page access token of Facebook be used as a permanent token if I just want to post something on the wall like user access token?

Its actually a vague question. It depends on what kind of posting you want to do. For eg:

1. If you want to post on a user's wall- there's nothing that a page access token can do
2. If you want to post a user's group/event etc. wall, again page access token has nothing to do with it.
3. If you want to **post on a page**, then yes you have to use the page access token in order to post on behalf of page itself.

**Page access tokens** are used in Graph API calls to manage Facebook Pages. To generate a page access token, an admin of the page must grant an extended permission called `manage_pages`. Once this permission has been granted, you can retrieve the page access token using the following Graph API request:

```
GET /{user-id}/accounts
```

You can also extend a page access token that will never expire. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261813/what-are-the-steps-to-getting-a-long-lasting-token-for-posting-to-a-facebook-fan/18322405#18322405) how to do that!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually it is used to post stuff on a page and I think this will work fine for the 3rd situation!