# Using Facebook page token to post in the wall of the user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with Facebook Graph API. I realized that I can get permanent (page) token and that I can use that token to post videos on the user's wall (not in the page wall, but in the user's one). It seems like I'm cheating the system because the permanent token has been granted to the page but I'm using it to post in the wall of the user. I'm happy with it but I'm afraid this may change in the future. What do you think? Do you think it is a fair use of the API? or do you think that this shouldn't be working at all?

My only concern is Facebook changes its mind in the future and then my code would stop working.
Some users seems to think that this is not even possible : [Facebook Page Access Token can be used to post stuff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051320/facebook-page-access-token-can-be-used-to-post-stuff)

But it works if you select user_actions.videos, publish_actions and manage_pages permissions. If you do that you will be posting videos to the user's wall with /me/videos API using the page permanent token.

Best regards,
Raúl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get a Page Token with publish_actions by requesting a User Token with publish_actions first, i guess that´s why.

That being said, you should not do it even if it´s possible. You can´t be 100% sure it will work forever, i´d even file it as a bug.