# How to post on facebook page as that page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fan-page

Let's say I've create a facebook page named MyPage.

When I am using a web interface of FB, I can either post on that wall as the user I am logged in as (personal user) or as a page instance, MyPage user.

Is it possible, via any of the available API's, to post on a facebook page as that page's user programmtically from my desktop application code?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Are you using the .Net SDK?

Comment: @madebydavid Yes, but we can work with any example.

Answer (score 0):

To post on facebook page as that page, you need an **page access token** of that page.

To get the page access token, you need-

- permission: `manage_pages`.
- API call: `/{page-id}?fields=access token`

(If you are not aware, you can test the graph api calls from: [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer))

In the posting code, just add a parameter: `access_token` and give it the page access token. That's it.

---

PS if you wish to extend this token, that'll never expire, you can get the login from here: [What are the Steps to getting a Long Lasting Token For Posting To a Facebook Fan Page from a Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261813/what-are-the-steps-to-getting-a-long-lasting-token-for-posting-to-a-facebook-fan/18322405#18322405)