# Facebook events graph not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get an Facebook page events. I've checked that the app id and app secret are correct and I still keep getting the error.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

ob_start();

require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';

$fb = new Facebook(array(
       'appid'=>'APPID',
       'secret'=>'APPSECRET'
      ) );
$page_events = $fb->api('/PAGEID/events?fields=description,location,name,owner,cover,start_time,end_time', 'GET');
printf ('<pre>%s</pre>', $page_events);

?>
```

The error message:

> Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you've implemented or not but your code is missing-

1. **User Login/Authentication**

   The code is not authenticating the user. After creating the `$fb` object; use this-

   ```
   $user_id = $fb->getUser();
   if($user_id) {
      try {

         // proceed your api calls - user is authenticated at this point

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
         $login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'manage_pages'));
         header ("Location: $login_url");
         error_log($e->getType());
         error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
   } else {
      $login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'manage_pages'));
      header ("Location: $login_url");
   }
   ```
2. **Permissions**

   The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/) says-

   For the page events-

   > - Any access token can be used to view publicly shared events.
   > - A `user access token` is required to retrieve events visible to that person.
   > - A `page access token` is required to retrieve any other events.

   I think you are trying to fetch all the events in a page, so you'll be needing the **page access token**.

   To get a page access token: `$fb->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");`. Use the token return with your original call to get all the page's events-

   ```
   $page_events = $fb->api('/PAGEID/events?access_token='.$page_access_token.'&fields=description,location,name,owner,cover,start_time,end_time', 'GET');
   ```

(If required, you can also get a never expiring page token for a page: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322405/1343690))

Comment: I'm trying to fetch event from a public page, do i still need to login/authenticate ?

Comment: yes of course. But for the public events you can ignore the page access token. simply authenticate the user and your api call will work

Comment: So now it redirects to a https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth... page, but nothing happens.