# Not able to get Facebook Reviews through PHP SDK V4. Error: (#210) Subject must be a page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use PHP SDK V4 to retrieve 'Facebook Page Ratings' in my website's page. For that I created an fb app, and got a **page access token** from Graph API Explorer.

As described in [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page). My code was working properly when I access ONLY page details

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}'
);
```

But when I try to retrieve ratings of that Facebook page as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/ratings)-

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}/ratings'
);
```

I get following Error-

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookPermissionException' with message '(#210) Subject must be a page.'.......

Why is that? Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error coz you're not using the **page access token** with the API call.

**Getting the page access token–**

Instead of using the page access token from the Graph API Explorer, get one from the API call. Remember that the user must authorize the app with `manage_pages` permission. You'l l get the page access token in the response of following call ([demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=pageid%3Ffields%3Daccess_token&version=v2.0))-

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}?fields=access_token'
);
```

<sub>PS, if required, you can also get a page access token of a page which you authored that **never** expires. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322405/1343690) answer.</sub>

**Using page access token with a call–**

To get the ratings you have to use the page access token with the API `/{page-id}/ratings`, just like this-

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}/ratings?access_token='.$page_access_token  //use the page access token obtained from above step here
);
```

---

**Note:**

From [**v2.0**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) onwards, the permissions other than `public_profile`, `email` and the `user_friends` need to the submitted for review before you can make your app live; else you wont be able to use them. Only the testers/admin/developers of the app will be able to test with those permissions until the permissions are reviewed.

So, you just have to submit login review before you make your app live. [Here are the details for login review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try to get page access token, in the output i'm getting only 'id' of the page(using print_r( $graphObject, 1 );)

Comment: That's why I've written- `Remember that the user must authorize the app with manage_pages permission`

Comment: While creating page access token i checked all check boxes including 'manage_pages'. Any way i'll check that again.

Comment: When I try to create an access token with permission 'manage_pages', it is giving this notice: The following permissions have not been approved for use: manage_pages.
If you make your app public, they will not be shown to people using your app. Submit them for review or learn more.

Comment: This warning is quite straight-forward right? I've explained this in the edit, pls check.

Comment: I created this app just to display fan page's reviews in my website. This is not a public app. As I am the admin, is there any way to skip this 'submit' process.

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly your app does; but if only YOU are going to login and use your data to the website, you can let your app in the development mode.