# Getting warning while creating a page access token with 'manage_pages' permission

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

When I try to get a page_access token with 'manage_pages' permission, i get following warning

> The following permissions have not been approved for use: manage_pages. If you make your app public, they will not be shown to people using your app. Submit them for review or learn more.

I am the admin of this facebook page.

Trying to retrieve My Fanpage's reviews in my website, through php sdk v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**v2.0**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) onwards, the permissions other than `public_profile`, `email` and the `user_friends` need to the submitted for review before you can make your app **live**; else you wont be able to use them. Only the testers/admin/developers of the app will be able to test with those permissions until the permissions are reviewed.

If you want to skip the review process, you can keep your app in the dev mode and use the **page access token** that will never expire. To generate such token , see the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261813/what-are-the-steps-to-getting-a-long-lasting-token-for-posting-to-a-facebook-fan/18322405#18322405).

Comment: Yes. the app is in dev mode, and i've generated a never expire token. It is working in 'Graph Explorer API', but not working when call it from php sdk. Error: '(#210) Subject must be a page'

Comment: Obviously you are missing a step here. This works like charm! Please follow the steps carefully.

Comment: Yes, it works like charm! All steps were followed to get never expire token. I got that error (#201: Subject must be a page) because, there was a session error in my code, which is resolved now. Thank you Sahil Mittal.