# Graph API with permanent access token - posts visible only for admin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I used Graph API permanent token to publish posts to the page's wall as Page.

All is good, but I can see posts - no on else sees them.

How can I fix this?

Here is the data I send to FB API to create post as Page:

```
array(7) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(2942) "Chevrolet is preparing to release its latest supercar model on the publicthe Corvette Stingray. As part of final testing and performance ratings, Corvette has enlisted a team of technical experts to put the car through its paces on the world-famous Nürbugring race course. This team is being headed up by Chevrolet Europes technical manager, Patrick Herrman, who is overseeing the two Corvette Stingray coupes that are undergoing this ultimate stress test.

The GM dynamics engineer, Jim Mero, had this to say about why Chevrolet chose to go overseas in testing their new model."

  ["picture"]=>
  string(73) "http://test.iwsghost.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/corvette-stingray.jpg"

  ["name"]=>
  string(115) "Chevrolet to Unleash All-New Corvette Stingray on Nürburgring | Nürburgring Lap Times [ nurburgringlaptimes.com ]"

  ["link"]=>
  string(92) "http://nurburgringlaptimes.com/chevrolet-to-unleash-all-new-corvette-stingray-on-nurburgring"

  ["caption"]=>
  string(50) "Nürburgring Lap Times [ nurburgringlaptimes.com ]"

  ["description"]=>
  string(2942) "Chevrolet is preparing to release its latest supercar model on the publicthe Corvette Stingray. As part of final testing and performance ratings, Corvette has enlisted a team of technical experts to put the car through its paces on the world-famous Nürbugring race course. This team is being headed up by Chevrolet Europes technical manager, Patrick Herrman, who is overseeing the two Corvette Stingray coupes that are undergoing this ultimate stress test."
}
```

I use the permanent token to do this from my server. This token I get by this tutorial - [What are the Steps to getting a Long Lasting Token For Posting To a Facebook Fan Page from a Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261813/what-are-the-steps-to-getting-a-long-lasting-token-for-posting-to-a-facebook-fan/18322405#18322405)

And posted all data by this API Path - `/{page-id}/feed`

As a result I can see this posts, because I am page's administrator, and I see this as page.No one more can see it.

How can I set permissions to make it opened for everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app must be in the **development mode**.

Until the app is in dev mode  only the admins, developers and testers of the app can see the posts. You can switch your app to **live** in the settings-

[image]

**Edit:**

Before making your app live, you must get the permissions **approved** by facebook else nobody but dev/admins/testers will see the posts.

> From [**v2.0**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) onwards, the permissions other than `public_profile`, `email` and the `user_friends` need to the submitted for review before you can make your app **live**; until then, only the testers/admin/developers of the app will be able to test app with those permissions.

See here for details on [Login Submission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login).

Comment: Unfortunally it is in live mode allready.

Screentshot
http://i.imgur.com/ciZbXWH.png