# How to get never expiring page access token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I'm developing a little Facebook app, that will post regularly (cronjob) to my Facebook fan page. I used this [tutorial](https://www.rocketmarketinginc.com/blog/get-never-expiring-facebook-page-access-token/), to get this token, but I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\\FacebookPermissionException' with message '(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action' in /path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php:128
```

I will post my source if asked, but I don't get any PHP parse or any other errors, just this, and I don't see any result on my page. If I check this access token, with the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) I see this:

```
App ID  my-app-id : My app name
Profile ID  my-page-id
User ID
my-admin-fb-profile-id : My Name 
User last installed this app via API v2.x
Issued  1422735069 (22 hours ago)
Expires Never
Valid   True
Origin  Web
Scopes  public_profile, read_stream, read_insights, manage_pages
```

What can be wrong? Can someone help me, please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the Steps to getting a Long Lasting Token For Posting To a Facebook Fan Page from a Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261813/what-are-the-steps-to-getting-a-long-lasting-token-for-posting-to-a-facebook-fan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error you're attempting to do something that you don't have permission to. It doesn't appear to be an expired token issue.

If you attempting to post to your fan page from your app you may need to get the "publish_actions" permission. [Click and scroll down to "Get Publishing Permissions"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.2)

Based on the debug under "Scopes" you're not currently asking for this permission.